# How to avoid proc sql in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a panel dataset at hourly frequency. I want to delete all observations if there are less than 200 observation at any given one hour interval. So I first count the number of observations `N` at each hour, then delete if `N` < 200. However, the proc sql common in step 2 use up all my C disk free space. Is there a better way to achieve my target?

```
data lib.data;
    set lib.data;
    retain I; by date hour;
    if first.date or first.hour then I=1; else I=I+1;
run;

proc sql;
    create table lib.data1
    as select a.*,  max(I) as N 
    from lib.data as a  
    group by date, hour
    order by date, hour;
quit; 

data lib.data (drop= i n);
    set lib.data;
if n < 200 then delete;
run;
```

Comment: It looks to me like your SQL statement is incorrect.  That's probably why it's chewing up all your disk space.  You need to include every field in table A in your group-by statement if it is also in your select statement and not used in a summary function.  Alternatively, change your select statement to read `select date, hour, max(i) as n` and it should work as desired.

Comment: @RobertPenridge I think that's true in SQL, but not SAS SQL since it will automatically remerge the data, but generates a warning to that effect.

Comment: @Reeza Well I guess technically the statement in syntactically correct (for SAS), but it's probably semantically incorrect for the OPs intention.  Personally I think SAS should generate an error unless some kind of additional option/switch is specified as I guarantee that 99% of the time it's used in this form it's a mistake.

Comment: @RobertPenridge - Actually it matches exactly the request. The request was to keep only those records where there were 200 or more observations within the same hour.  You could re-phrase it as a join with a sub query, but why not just let SAS do it for you automatically?

Comment: @Tom, why not just use a `having ` statement?  No need for a sub-query, no confusing and slow re-merging....

Comment: That's a great point. Submit it as a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double DOW loop.  The first one will count the number of records. Then the second one can use that count to conditionally execute an OUTPUT statement.

```
data want ;
  do until (last.hour);
    set lib.data;
    by date hour;
    n=sum(n,1);
  end;
  do until (last.hour);
    set lib.data;
    by date hour;
    if n >= 200 then output;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 2):

`PROC SQL` in itself is not the problem. It's the unintended consequences (such as remerging of data) of not having all of your non-summary columns in the `GROUP BY`. Here's a SQL solution that hopefully shouldn't blow up your drive.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select
    a.*
from
    lib.data  a
    join
    (select 
        date,
        hour,
        count(*)
    from
        lib.data
    group by date, hour
    having count(*) >= 200)  b
        on
        a.date = b.date and
        a.hour = b.hour
;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use hash table to store first 200 records. And when you reach 200th record output data from hash table and the rest observations from current hour.
The code below shows how it could works:

```
data lib.data (drop= counter rc);
    set lib.data;
    by date hour;
    retain counter 0;

    If _N_ =1 then do;
        declare hash hs(multidata:'yes');
        hs.definekey('date','hour');
        hs.definedone();
    end;
/*if first record in hour zero counter*/
    if first.hour then do;
        counter=0;
    end;
/*increment counter*/
    counter = counter+1;
/*if counter less then 200 add record to hash table*/
    if counter < 200 then do;
        hs.add();
    end;
    /*if counter=200 output current record and record from hash*/
    if counter = 200 then do;
        output;
        rc = hs.find();
        do while(rc=0);
            output;
            rc= hs.find_next();
        end;
    end;
    /*if counter greater then 200 output current record*/
    if counter > 200 then output;
/*if last record in hour clear hash*/
    if last.hour then do;
        hs.clear();
    end;
run;
```